# Is it possible to make a PCL library that contains the control that use custom render?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

Is it possible to make a library that contains the control that use custom render? 
For example, I want to create customized DatePicker control (Customized via custom render), that would be reused in many other projects. My goal is to create control you can just add to the XAML without writing any platform-specific code or , maybe, only some initialization.

Comment: yea its possible :)

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can make it as Xamarin Plugin.
Check out this post https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-reusable-plugins-for-xamarin-forms/